# Collections.sort comparing 2 objects throws null pointer exception

Tags: java, sorting

i am using collections.sort methods int compare to compare 2 objects distance parameter and sort them according to distance in ascending order.
here is what i am doing to compare it

```
Collections.sort(venuesList, new Comparator<FoursquareVenue>() {

                @Override
                public int compare(FoursquareVenue lhs, FoursquareVenue rhs) {                  


                    return lhs.getDistance().compareTo(rhs.getDistance());  
                }
            });
```

I think there is just some small silly thing i am missing to do but i couldn't figure it out whats the problem
error says something like this

```
07-12 14:52:51.018: E/AndroidRuntime(1377): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
07-12 14:52:51.018: E/AndroidRuntime(1377): java.lang.NullPointerException:println needs a message
07-12 14:52:51.018: E/AndroidRuntime(1377): at android.util.Log.println_native(Native Method)
07-12 14:52:51.018: E/AndroidRuntime(1377): atandroid.util.Log.v(Log.java:117)
```

I think i need to handle the null values of the object but i don't know how can i do that?

Answer (score 1):

The second argument to `Log.v(...)` needs to be a `String` and the `getDistance()` method probably returns `null`

To prevent the exception you can do something like this:

```
if (lhs != null && rhs != null && lhs.getDistance() != null && rhs.getDistance() != null) {
    Log.v("lhs Distance", lhs.getDistance());
    Log.v("rhs Distance", rhs.getDistance());
    return lhs.getDistance().compareTo(rhs.getDistance());
} else {
    return -1;
}
```

Comment: Actually it is what you said.. it still throws same exception and how should i handle that if getDistance is returning null value...

Comment: @ChristianYoung Yes, I've changed my answer, it may be returning `null` hence the `NullPointerException`

Comment: you are right i just saw in Logcat that when lhs.getDistance returns null it shows null pointer exception so what should i do to handle that?

Comment: Log.v is just to print the output on my console to figure out whats wrong changing those value didn't effect the error i need to solve the return statement... consider Log.v statement is not in code

Comment: @ChristianYoung I've edited my question again,  the `Log.v(...)` method was the one causing the error but I guess by fixing it you got another `NullPointerException`  because `lhs.getDistance()` returned `null` when you were trying to compare it `lhs.getDistance().compareTo(...)`